# Rmagick installed: `require': no such file to load -- RMagick (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I run the command ruby billede.rb in my lib folder in rails I get the error:

```
C:\Rails\myapp\lib>ruby billede.rb
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require':
no such file to load -- RMagick (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:i
n `require'
        from billede.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

My Billede.rb:

```
class Billede
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'

if !ARGV[0]
    puts "Usage: watermark /image.png"
    exit
end

image = Magick::Image.read(ARGV[0]).first

mark = Magick::Image.new(image.columns, image.rows)

gc = Magick::Draw.new
gc.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
gc.pointsize = 32
gc.font_family = "Helvetica"
gc.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
gc.stroke = 'none'
gc.annotate(mark, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Watermark\nby\nRMagick")

mark = mark.shade(true, 310, 30)

image.composite!(mark, Magick::CenterGravity, Magick::HardLightCompositeOp)

out = ARGV[0].sub(/\./, "-wm.")
puts "Writing #{out}"
image.write(out)
end
```

I have installed RMagick.

Update when installing the gem.

In my gemfile I have:

```
gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'
```

When running bundle install:

```
C:\Rails\myapp>bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.1)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.9)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.9)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.4)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.30)
Using actionpack (3.0.9)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.9)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.9)
Using activeresource (3.0.9)
Using addressable (2.2.6)
Using bundler (1.0.18)
Using multipart-post (1.1.4)
Using faraday (0.7.6)
Using friendly_id (4.0.0)
Using hashie (1.2.0)
Using json (1.6.1)
Using multi_json (1.0.4)
Using mysql (2.8.1)
Using oauth2 (0.5.2)
Using omniauth (1.0.2)
Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.0)
Using omniauth-facebook (1.2.0)
Using rdoc (3.10)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.9)
Using rails (3.0.9)
Using rest-client (1.6.7)
Installing rmagick (2.13.1) with native extensions C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby
/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:552:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR
: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

        C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for snprintf() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdin
t.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AcquireImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,s
tdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,
stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AffinityImages() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h
,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoGammaImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h
,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AutoLevelImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h
,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for BlueShiftImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h
,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ConstituteComponentTerminus() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,
math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DeskewImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,st
dint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EncipherImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,
stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for EqualizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,
time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FloodfillPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,t
ime.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for FunctionImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,
time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticIndexQueue() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.
h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,ti
me.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,
time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for GetVirtualPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time
.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelImageColors() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time
.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelColorsImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math
.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LevelizeImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,
time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for LiquidRescaleImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,ti
me.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickLibAddendum() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,tim
e.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for OpaquePaintImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math
.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueueAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,
time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemapImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,std
int.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for RemoveImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,t
ime.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SelectiveBlurImageChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,ma
th.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageAlphaChannel() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,
time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetImageArtifact() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time
.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SetMagickMemoryMethods() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.
h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SparseColorImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time
.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for SyncAuthenticPixels() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,t
ime.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImage() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h
,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for TransparentPaintImageChroma() in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,
math.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for QueryMagickColorname() new signature... yes
checking for Image.type in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdin
t.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.kerning in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h
,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interline_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,mat
h.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DrawInfo.interword_spacing in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,mat
h.h,time.h,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for DitherMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,std
int.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for MagickFunction in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,s
tdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h
,stdint.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for long double in assert.h,ctype.h,stdio.h,stdlib.h,math.h,time.h,stdi
nt.h,sys/types.h,wand/MagickWand.h... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.CopyAlphaChannel... yes
checking for AlphaChannelType.BackgroundAlphaChannel... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.BlurCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.DistortCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearBurnCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.LinearDodgeCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.MathematicsCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PegtopLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.PinLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompositeOperator.VividLightCompositeOp... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT1Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT3Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.DXT5Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.ZipSCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.PizCompression... yes
checking for CompressionType.Pxr24Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44Compression... yes
checking for CompressionType.B44ACompression... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BarrelInverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearForwardDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.BilinearReverseDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.DePolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolarDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.PolynomialDistortion... yes
checking for DistortImageMethod.ShepardsDistortion... yes
checking for DitherMethod.NoDitherMethod... yes
checking for FilterTypes.KaiserFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.WelshFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.ParzenFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.LagrangeFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BohmanFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.BartlettFilter... yes
checking for FilterTypes.SentinelFilter... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PowEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LogEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdBlackEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ThresholdWhiteEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.GaussianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.ImpulseNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.LaplacianNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.MultiplicativeNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.PoissonNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.UniformNoiseEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.CosineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.SineEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickEvaluateOperator.AddModulusEvaluateOperator... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArcsinFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.ArctanFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.PolynomialFunction... yes
checking for MagickFunction.SinusoidFunction... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.FlattenLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MergeLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.MosaicLayer... yes
checking for ImageLayerMethod.TrimBoundsLayer... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.HorizontalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.VerticalTileEdgeVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for VirtualPixelMethod.CheckerTileVirtualPixelMethod... yes
checking for ruby/io.h... yes
checking for rb_frame_this_func() in ruby.h,ruby/io.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile


======================================================================
Wed 25Apr12 14:10:35
This installation of RMagick 2.13.1 is configured for
Ruby 1.9.2 (i386-mingw32) and ImageMagick 6.7.6
======================================================================



make


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2
.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick
/gem_make.out
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:530:in `b
lock in build_extensions'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `e
ach'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:505:in `b
uild_extensions'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `i
nstall'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:101:in `block in install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/ruby
gems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:91:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/ruby
gems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:57:in `block in run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:49:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/cli.
rb:220:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle:13:in
 `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'

C:\Rails\myapp>
```

Comment: Did RMagick install successfully? See [the windows notes](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#win) for installation instructions.

Comment: Shouldn't RMagick be in lowercase? (in your require line, I mean)

Comment: @d11wtq, yes, the casing in RMagick is correct :)

Comment: Paste the `make` output from gem_make.out

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bundler (when you are using Rails you are using Bundler, too) you need to add RMagick to your Gemfile. Bundler only loads the bundled gems into your environment.

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems

# loads of other stuff

gem 'rmagick'
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

You need to install imagemagic first:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
```

Then add the ruby wrapper to your gemfile:

```
gem 'rmagick'
```

And finally tell Bundler to download rmagic:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

External scripts in your rails project should be run as follows:

```
bundle exec lib/billede.rb <params>
```

(make sure you have `gem 'RMagick'` in the Gemfile)

this way in case of any dependency issues you'll get more descriptive output.

Comment: I have updated my question with further information. When I run the command I get: C:\Rails\myapp>bundle exec lib/billede.rb
Could not find gem 'rmagick (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gem
file.

Comment: C:\Rails\myapp>bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'RMagick (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gem
file.

C:\Rails\myapp>